# Beamer: How to place graphics at the bottom of a frame

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, vertical-alignment, overlays

I want to achieve that included graphics are always on the bottom of the frame, so that their position isn't influenced by the length of the text above.

I tried the `figure` enviroment without success and the `\vfill` also doesn't give the wished success.

Here is some similar example source (and you can download the images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPXVB.jpg) I'm using the same):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xspace}

\begin{document}

\frame{

    \only<1-3>{Blablabla1}
    \only<4>{Blablabla2}
    \only<5>{Blablabla3}
    \only<6>{Blablabla4}
    \only<7>{Blablabla5}
    \only<8>{Blablabla6}
    \only<9>{Blablabla7}

    \vfill

    \visible<3->{%
        \includegraphics<1-3>[width=\linewidth]{img/1.png}
        \includegraphics<4>[width=\linewidth]{img/2.png}
        \includegraphics<5>[width=\linewidth]{img/3.png}
        \includegraphics<6>[width=\linewidth]{img/4.png}
        \includegraphics<7>[width=\linewidth]{img/5.png}
        \includegraphics<8>[width=\linewidth]{img/6.png}
        \includegraphics<9>[width=\linewidth]{img/7.png}
        \includegraphics<10>[width=\linewidth]{img/8.png}
    }

}

\end{document}
```

---

alexurba gave me the answer.

I have to add the `[b]` option to the `frame` enviroment. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs thanks for the advice. I made the source compilable and added a link to the pictures im using so people can download them.

Comment: First, the code is still not compilable; there is no `\begin{document}` for starters (and obviously the images will be missing). Apart from that, I think you are looking for `\frame[b]{...}`, which will vertically align the frame content at the bottom. I personally use the `frame` environment: `\begin{frame}[b] ... \end{frame}`. Finally, the `graphicx` package is already loaded by `beamer`, so no need for `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: @alexurba Ah, sorry for the inconveniences with the compiling. I added the \begin{document} in my editor but forgot to copy that version. And thank you, the [b] option was exaclty what I was looking for. Could you make an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\frame` command takes the vertical alignment as an optional argument.  `\frame[b]{...}` will align the frame contents at the bottom, which is what the OP was looking for (use `c` for *centered* and `t` for *top*).

The `frame` environment supports the same arguments (`\begin{frame}[b] ... \end{frame}`).

Adding the alignment option to the sample document of the original question results in:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame[b]{
    \only<1-3>{Blablabla1}
    \only<4>{Blablabla2}
    \only<5>{Blablabla3}
    \only<6>{Blablabla4}
    \only<7>{Blablabla5}
    \only<8>{Blablabla6}
    \only<9>{Blablabla7}

    \vfill

    \visible<3->{%
        \includegraphics<1-3>[width=\linewidth]{img/1.png}
        \includegraphics<4>[width=\linewidth]{img/2.png}
        \includegraphics<5>[width=\linewidth]{img/3.png}
        \includegraphics<6>[width=\linewidth]{img/4.png}
        \includegraphics<7>[width=\linewidth]{img/5.png}
        \includegraphics<8>[width=\linewidth]{img/6.png}
        \includegraphics<9>[width=\linewidth]{img/7.png}
        \includegraphics<10>[width=\linewidth]{img/8.png}
    }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The beamer slides effectively contain a `\vfill` at the top and/or bottom of the frame, depending on your vertical alignment. I don't think there is one that does not have any. Hence, in top alignment, your contents are vertically centered below the text at the top.

The solution is simple: use a stronger fill **instead of `\vfill`**:

```
\vskip 0pt plus 1filll
```

Yes, that is three `l`. If you want, you can do a

```
\providecommand{\vfilll}{\vskip 0pt plus 1filll minus 0pt}
```

and then just use `\vfilll` as a stronger fill.

**Alternatively**, you can cancel out the vfill by placing this at the end of your frame (assuming top alignment):

```
\vskip 0pt plus -1fill% Bottom align
```

This time with two `l`, because beamer added `1fill` for top alignment. For center alignment, use `-1.5fill` (see `beamerbaseframe.sty`).